# How to remove coupon dropdown feature

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I want to remove the coupon drop down feature and just have the input field and 'add coupon' button on the checkout page. Does anyone know how I can get rid of the dropdown feature?
Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if ( ! wc_coupons_enabled() ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! WC()->cart->applied_coupons ) {
    $info_message = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_message', __( 'Promo code?', 'woocommerce' ) . ' <a href="#" class="showcoupon">' . __( 'Click here to enter your code', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' );
    wc_print_notice( $info_message, 'notice' );
}
?>

<form class="checkout_coupon" method="post" style="display:none">

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Promo Code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: On checkout page, by default WooCommerce renders coupon field as input field and not dropdown. Not sure how you are seeing it as dropdown. Are you using any extra plugin for coupon. Please share your website link.

Comment: Can you leave url here, I see there is no dropdown here only 2 inputs, the text input and submit for that text. Maybe you have some javascript which is animating you this area or something?

Comment: @ItsMePN and Usce, perhaps you're using older versions of WooCommerce? I see the animated open that the OP described.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this action.
Put this line into your active theme **functions.php** file

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
```

Comment: @T.doe this solution work for you... if not then I will give you another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Coupon Field Using Option

If you are really fed up with the coupons, you can easily remove the coupon field altogether. To do that, go to the WooCommerce > Settings page, click on the ‘Checkout’ tab. Uncheck the ‘Enable the use of coupons’ and click ‘Save Changes’ button. At this point, you no longer have the coupon field anywhere in your store.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css - the form is hidden by default, but can be targeted like this:

```
.woocommerce-checkout form.checkout_coupon{
    display:block
}
```

(put that in style.css)

Answer (score 0):

[Steven](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/226224/133859) is correct, but new WooCommerce styles apply styles to that form differently now so the style code should be

`.woocommerce form.checkout_coupon { display:block !important; }`